# JSON Added to Database as Unicode

Tags: python, json, django, unicode

I'm trying to save a JSON request as strings in a database but having some issues: for some reason, my data is being saved to the database as a Unicode string. What I mean by this is that strings are being saved like this in the database:

```
[{u'content': u'Treehouse', u'name': u'opportunity_name'}, {u'content': u'Robert', u'name': u'user_firstname'}, {u'content': u'Warren', u'name': u'client_firstname'}, {u'content': u'Buffett', u'name': u'client_lastname'}, {u'content': u'Form ABC123', u'name': u'my_name'}]
```

When they should be like this (without the u's):

```
[{'content': 'Treehouse', 'name': 'opportunity_name'}, {'content': 'Robert'...
```

Here's my code, in views.py (data in this can also prints as unicode):

```
@csrf_exempt
def send_aggregate_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        print 'data'
        # the output from this print statement is the same, with leading 'u's
        print data
        serializer = SendAggregateSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(data,status=201)
```

models.py:

```
class SendAggregate(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    global_merge_vars = models.TextField()
    subject_merge_vars = models.TextField()
    to_email = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    to_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    template = models.ForeignKey(Template, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

serializers.py:

```
class SendAggregateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SendAggregate
        fields = ('id', 'created', 'is_sent', 'to_email', 'to_name', 'global_merge_vars', 'subject_merge_vars', 'template')
```

If it helps, here is the output from `serializer.validated_data`:

```
OrderedDict([(u'to_email', u'rob.grzesik@gmail.com'), (u'to_name', u'Recipient Name'), (u'global_merge_vars', u"[{u'content': u'Treehouse', u'name': u'opportunity_name'}, {u'content': u'Robert', u'name': u'user_firstname'}, {u'content': u'Warren', u'name': u'client_firstname'}, {u'content': u'Buffett', u'name': u'client_lastname'}, {u'content': u'Form ABC123', u'name': u'loan_task_subject'}]"), (u'subject_merge_vars', u'[]'), (u'template', <Template: my_name>)])
```

Comment: Please add the code where you save json into the database.

Comment: Why are you explicitly loading the JSON string? That's what a serializer does.

Comment: JSON is unicode but django and your database may be okay with that. Here is what the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/unicode/) say.

Comment: The "should be" you provided is not valid JSON either since JSON uses double quotes. What you see in your database is most likely a string representation of a python dict.

Comment: @НазарТопольський - He is showing the python representation of the data that django uses, not the JSON string or what is character-by-character in the database.

Comment: @spectras added code where it saves to the database

Comment: @tdelaney I am actually showing what is in the database. how can this be fixed?

Comment: @НазарТопольський you're probably right, how can I fix this to put the JSON string into the database instead?

Comment: @Rob - how do you know that is in the database? Did you test it in python by using django to read the data? Or did you read from sql or some database management tool and print exactly what what returned? If you read it in django, then you are printing the representations of python objects because that's what django does - convert database data to python objects.

Comment: @tdelaney I ran a select statement in the database and directly copy/ pasted that string from the response

Comment: @tdelaney if it helps: the string already looks like that after json.loads(), the print statement afterward has the same output

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! Simply switched over to using another JSON package:

```
import simplejson as json
```